# Is 'embark in' right? - 1892 UK?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, legalese

[Source:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlill_v_Carbolic_Smoke_Ball_Co#Lord_Justice_Bowen) Carlill v Carbolic Smoke Ball Company [1892], judgement of Bowen LJ

> A further argument for the defendants was that this was a nudum pactum - that there was no consideration for the promise — that taking the influenza was only a condition, and that the using the smoke ball was only a condition, and that there was no consideration at all; in fact, that there was no request, express or implied, to use the smoke ball. Now, I will not enter into an elaborate discussion upon the law as to requests in this kind of contracts. I will simply refer to Victors v Davies[8] and Serjeant Manning's note to Fisher v Pyne,[9] which everybody ought to read who wishes to embark **in** this controversy. The short answer, to abstain from academical discussion, is, it seems to me, that there is here a request to use involved in the offer.

'this controversy' isn't physical, so why **in**? Should the preposition be [on/upon](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/embark) instead?

Comment: An ngram search will show that *embark in* was common in the mid 19th century, and thereafter began to decline. Around 1910, *embark on* and *embark upon* began to overtake it.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embark+in%2Cembark+upon%2Cembark+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cembark%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembark%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembark%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Why should "in" be more 'physical' than "upon" or "on"? You can *engage in a discussion*.  (Not my downvote, BTW. Not this time, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

In the end it does not really make too much of a difference, but I would think "in" would be right here. This is because a controversy, in this context is seen as a argument or debate. You have to be "in" the argument, not on or upon it.